# Ruby/Rspec: Possible to compare the content of two objects?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I've created 2 different objects in ruby with exactly the same attributes and values.

I'd like to compare now that the content of both objects is the same but the following comparisons:

```
actual.should == expected
actual.should eq(expected)
actual.should (be expected)
```

fail with:

```
  Diff:
  @@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
  -#<Station:0x2807628
  +#<Station:0x2807610
```

Is there any way in rspec/ruby to easily achieve this?

Cheers!!

Answer (score 17):

An idiomatic way to do this is to override the `#==` operator:

```
class Station
  def ==(o)
    primary_key == o.primary_key
  end

  def hash
    primary_key.hash
  end
end
```

When you do this, you generally want to override the `#hash` method as well.  It is less common to  override `#eql?` or `#equal?`.

**EDIT**: Another thing you can do in this specific case, which does not involve overriding `#==`, is to make a [custom RSpec matcher](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/custom-matchers).

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the answer, trying to understand this method. Why do we need to override `#hash` and when would that be invoked?

How should we make this comparison once implemented, something like `station_one.==(station_two)`?

Comment: @mickael: no problem.  You need to override `#hash` so that the behavior of the object continues to make sense when you use it as a key in a Hash object.  You make use of the overridden `#==` operator in `Rspec` simply by doing `obj1.should == obj2` in an `it` block or similar.

Answer (score 17):

Use the have_attributes matcher to specify that an object's attributes match the expected attributes:

```
  Person = Struct.new(:name, :age)
  person = Person.new("Jim", 32)

  expect(person).to have_attributes(:name => "Jim", :age => 32)
  expect(person).to have_attributes(:name => a_string_starting_with("J"), :age => (a_value > 30) )
```

[Relishapp RSpec Docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/have-attributes-matcher)

Comment: This is what I prefer and if you're looking to use this on an array of objects, [Ben Pickles](https://www.benpickles.com/articles/73-testing-an-array-of-objects-with-rspec-have_attributes) reminds us you can do `match_array([have_attributes...])`.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late, but you could serialize it, per example:

```
require 'json'

expect(actual.to_json).to eq(expected.to_json) #new rspec syntax
actual.to_json.should eq(expected.to_json) #old rspec syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider overloading the equal operator on the object.